# How should I wrap an object that is from an unknown source

Tags: java, wrapper

I have an application with a number of interface implementations with an unknown source. I wanted to clean up my source code so that I do not need to write:

```
A a = AFactory.getImpl();
B b = a.getB();
if(b == null) return;
b.doSomething();
```

Which becomes very long winded. Should I wrap this object so that `A` will never return `null` from `getB()`; and if that is a good idea, how should I do that, Should I provide an implementation that throws an error like `InvalidImplemetationException` and force it to be caught.

Comment: Everything you've suggested seems right to me:  Make sure null is never returned, and throw an exception if null is encountered.  Whether you should force that exception to be caught—that is, whether it should be a checked exception—depends on whether null can be returned in a proper runtime configuration and whether applications can actually do something about it other than logging and/or exiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the Null Object Pattern: define a value of `B` that encapsulates the behaviour you want when you don't really have a `B`.  In this case that means `doSomething()` does nothing.

`B` would look like this:

```
public class B {
    public static final B NULL = new B() {
        public void doSomething() {
        }
    };

    public static B fromA(A a) {
        B b = a.getB();
        return b == null ? NULL : b;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
A a = AFactory.getImpl();
B.fromA(a).doSomething();
```

If you can change `AFactory.getImpl`, have it return `B.NULL` instead of `null`.  Then you don't need `B.fromA` and you can do this instead:

```
A a = AFactory.getImpl();
a.getB().doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend you putting the `b == null` code in the `getB` function.

It really seems that you did some research and picked a very good exception.

A good alternative is instead of throwing an exception returning a new object of `B`.